# Jquery Radio Button Checked, Whole Page quickly flicks

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has a question which has two radio options (Yes and No).

I managed to get the code working fine, but when i click yes out of the radio button the whole screen flashes very quickly.

I have never seen this before. can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".pension_hide").css("display","none");

    $("#q32081_q11_0").click(function(){

        if($("#q32081_q11_0").is("input:radio"))
        {
            $(".pension_hide").show("fast");    
        }
        else
        {
            $(".pension_hide").hide("fast");
        }

    });
});
```

I also have a radio button called q32081_q11_1 which is the no button, i also want this to remove the field when i have checked it.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: can you show us the html of these radio buttons

Comment: or better an example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: do u want this ??  check this : http://jsfiddle.net/bztJZ/1/

Comment: The input fields are q32081_q11_0 and q32081_q11_1 would you be able to modify it so it works with that id. So yes is q32081_q11_0 and no is q32081_q11_1. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Jake check now `http://jsfiddle.net/bztJZ/2/`

Comment: @diEcho, ah sorry dude, not the value tags, the id numbers. i would just change them, but im using this shit ass content management system. http://jsfiddle.net/YjwSh/

Comment: @Jake here is your solution for above `http://jsfiddle.net/YjwSh/1/`

Comment: For some reason, when i click on yes, in the browser, it flashes really quickly i thought i screwed up the code? Your code works great though. i have no idea why its doing this because this is the only javascript code on the page?

Comment: I dont have enough points yet to upvote otherwise i would!

Answer (score 0):

@Jake instead of checking on id

check on value bcoz each input has a unique 'value' attribute like below

`var var_name = $("input[name='radio_name']:checked").val();`

if u want to get the currently selected radio button's id:

```
var id = $("input[name='radio_name']:checked").attr('id');
```

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bztJZ/4/)

Comment: the input types i have have two seperate id numbers q32081_q11_0 and q32081_q11_1. How cna i make it so one shows it and the other one closes it?